# Colouring a finite set of sticks placed on a line either in red or blue

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a set of finitely many sticks which all have a finite length (all sticks aren't necessarily the same lengths) that are all placed on an infinitely long line such that these sticks may be overlapping partially, completely or not at all. Is it possible to colour in every stick in this set red or blue such that on every point $p$ of the line, the amount of red sticks and blue sticks differs by $-1$, $0$ or $1$?

Comment: No I just wasn't exctly 100% sure under which category it fell so I decided to put both. But I guess you're right

Comment: Why doesn't putting them all down so they don't overlap at all work?

Comment: @Sudix You don't get to place them where you want them. You are given an arrangement of sticks on the line. The problem is whether you can always find a colouring with the desired property, no matter how the sticks are placed. No, you are not allowed to move the sticks, that would be cheating.

Comment: And the problem statement is perfectly unambiguous and clear. In the first sentence, you are **given** some sticks which have already been **placed** on the line. In the second sentence you are asked if you can **colour** the sticks so that something happens. Nothing is said about rearranging the sticks to your liking.

Comment: By the way what's the source of this problem? What kind of course or book is it from, or is it from a competition?

Comment: You seem to have edited the question to replace it with a different question. Please don't do that - especially when you've already gotten answers to the first question! If you want to ask another question, ask the other question separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such a colouring is possible. My proof uses some basic ideas from [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

Suppose $n$ sticks are placed on the real line. Number the sticks arbitrarily from $1$ to $n$, and suppose the $i^\text{th}$ stick occupies the interval $(a_i,b_i)$, that is, its left end is at $a_i$ and its right end is at $b_i$. Without loss of generality we can assume that no endpoints coincide, so that $a_1,b_1,\dots,a_n,b_n$ are $2n$ distinct points. Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{2n}$ be the same $2n$ points listed in their order on the line from left to right, so that $x_1\lt x_2\lt\cdots\lt x_{2n}$. We will make the set
$$V=\{a_1,b_1,\dots,a_n,b_n\}=\{x_1,\dots,x_{2n}\}$$
the vertex set of a graph $G$. The graph has two kinds of edges: the $n$ **stick edges** $a_1b_1,a_2b_2,\dots,a_nb_n$, and the $n$ **non-stick edges** $x_1x_2,x_3x_4,\dots,x_{2n-1}x_{2n}$.

Now $G$ is a regular graph of degree $2$, since each vertex is incident with exactly two edges, one stick edge and one non-stick edge. However, $G$ is not (necessarily) a simple graph, as it may have multiple edges; for instance, if $a_1=x_1$ and $b_1=x_2$, then the vertices $x_1$ and $x_2$ are joined by two edges, forming a cycle of length $2$.

Since each vertex has degree $2$, the graph $G$ consists of one or more vertex-disjoint cycles. Moreover, each cycle has even length, since its edges are alternately sticky and non-sticky. Therefore the graph is $2$-colourable, that is, we can colour each vertex red or blue so that adjacent vertices have different colours.

Finally, we colour each stick with the colour of its left endpoint.

As we traverse the line from left to right, the quantity "red sticks minus blue sticks", initially zero, increases by one each time we pass a red vertex (either the left end of a red stick or the right end of a blue stick) and decreases by one each time we pass a blue vertex. Since $x_{2i-1}$ and $x_{2i}$ have different colours, that quantity will be $0$ whenever we have passed an even number of vertices, $\pm1$ whenever we have passed an odd number of vertices.

**P.S.** I've been asked to explain why I can assume that no endpoints coincide. Well, suppose we have some coincidences. Perturb the sticks slightly to get rid of the coincidences, and then find a good colouring for the perturbed arrangement. That means that the vertices partition the line into intervals where the quantity we care about is $0$ or $\pm1$. Now, if we slide the sticks back where they were, I claim the colouring is still good, because all that happens is that some of those intervals close up and disappear.

Comment: I thought of this a bit and I don't fully understand why you can suppose that no two points  coincide without loss of generality. Would someone mind explaining this to me?

Comment: Other than that I wish to thank you for this answer!

Comment: sorry for being a bit of a pain but I'm not sure I understand the last paragraph. Suppose that four consecutive points on the line are $a_k$, $a_{k+1}$, $b_k$, $b_{k+1}$ in that order with $a_k$ coloured in red. Then red vertex $b_k$ corresponds to the right end of a red stick, which is not one of the cases you mentioned

Comment: $a_k$ and $b_k$ are adjacent vertices, so they must have different colours. If $a_k$ is red, then $b_k$ must be blue.

Comment: Amazing answer! Can you share any insight on how you came up with this?

Comment: That's a nice image :-) I also found it a hard problem, and slightly frustrating because I felt strongly that the answer had to be positive but couldn't find a way to prove it – I'm glad that you did!

Comment: @joriki I spent a couple days in mostly aimless scribbling, but in retrospect it seems obvious what has to be done. Watch how the quantity "red sticks minus blue sticks" changes as we traverse the line from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. It increments by $+1$ when we pass the left end of a red stick or the right end of a blue stick, by $-1$ when we pass the right end of a red stick or the left end of a blue stick. So the two ends of each stick have different signs/"colours". To keep it between $\pm1$, we need $x_1$ & $x_2$ to have different signs, likewise $x_3$ & $x_4$, etc. So there's the graph we

Comment: @joriki have to $2$-colour. Believe it or not, it actually took me a while to figure out why that graph doesn't contain any odd cycles. (It's the union of two matchings. Duh. Or is it doh? I'm not sure I understand the difference.) So the closest thing to a "clever idea" is "keep track of how red sticks minus blue sticks changes as you travel from left to right". I'm not sure that deserves an "aha".

Comment: @bof: You're understating the creative ideas in the proof :-) Of course I also tried to "keep track of how red sticks minus blue sticks changes as you travel from left to right", but it didn't occur to me that this could be achieved with a graph with two types of edges, one type determined by the geometry and the other by the sticks. I don't think it would have occurred to me if I'd spent days instead of just an hour aimlessly scribbling, either.

Comment: @joriki I've known some really clever people, and I'm sure some of them would have solved this little puzzle in 5 minutes if not instantly. Anyway, I'm glad you like my work — not everyone agrees, the first vote cast on this answer was the down vote!